# Propel NestedSet creating Balanced Tree

Tags: symfony1, propel, nested-sets

I'm trying to use Propel's NestedSet feature.  However, I'm missing something about inserting such that the tree is balanced as it is created (i.e. fill it in horizontally).

Say I have these elements:

```
       root
  r1c1      r1c2
r2c1 r2c2
```

I want to insert r2c3 as the 1st child of r1c2 (i.e. fill row 2 before starting on row 3).

My first stab at this was to create this function:

```
function where(User $root,$depth=0)
{
  $num = $root->getNumberOfDescendants();
  if ( $num < 2 )
    return $root;
  foreach($root->getChildren() as $d)
  {
    if ( $d->getNumberOfChildren() < 2 )
    {
      return $d;
    }
  }
  foreach($root->getChildren() as $d)
  {
    return where($d, $depth+1);
  }
}
```

However, this will insert a child on r2c1, rather at r1c2 as I want.

Is there a way to insert an entry into the tree at the next available spot somehow?

TIA
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks to http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/, I found that this algorithm will do what I want:

```
function where($root)
{
  $num = $root->getNumberOfDescendants();
  if ( $num < 2 )
    return $root;

  $finder = DbFinder::from('User')->
    where('LeftId','>=',$root->getLeftId())->
    where('RightId','<=',$root->getRightId())->
    whereCustom('user.RightId = user.LeftId + ?',1,'left')->
    whereCustom('user.RightId = user.LeftId + ?',3,'right')->
    combine(array('left','right'),'or')->
    orderBy('ParentId');
    return $finder->findOne();
}
```

It basically executes this SQL:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM user u
WHERE u.LEFT_ID >= $left AND u.RIGHT_ID <= $right AND
  (u.RIGHT_ID = u.LEFT_ID+1 OR u.RIGHT_ID = u.LEFT_ID+3)
ORDER BY u.PARENT_ID
LIMIT 1
```

A leaf has RIGHT=LEFT+1, A node with 1 child has RIGHT=LEFT+3.  By adding the ORDER BY u.PARENT_ID, we find the highest node in the tree available.  If you use LEFT_ID or RIGHT_ID, it does not balance the tree.